# looping instead of manual input of multiple initial numbers variable Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a variable (`grass`) where you set in an initial number of grass. I want to see the result for different initial numbers, such as 50, 100, 150, ...., 1000, but it is too troublesome to set it manually, then run one by one. Is there anyway where I can just set a loop with 50 as the increment and stop at 1000, then release a certain value. Is that possible in Net Logo?

I have tried using the for function for other programming languages, but I do not know if it works here.

Comment: Jen, you should make the BehaviorSpace suggestion a proper answer, so it can be accepted: it is undoubtedly the right answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at BehaviorSpace - it's in the Tools menu. This is the batch simulation tool that exports the results so you can then do a summary etc. This will also allow you to do multiple repetitions for each of these values so you can calculate the average results for each, which is important when your simulation has randomness. There is a specific manual in the documentation, see https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html